# Hotchocolate GraphQl schema does not support record struct

Tags: c#, struct, graphql, record, hotchocolate

I have the schema definition below. Which while the server runs without error, the Chilicream IDE reports `schema unavailable`. The same code works fine if I change `record struct` to either `record` or `class`

Does Hotchocolate not support `record struct`?

```
    public record struct Money(long Cents);
    public class DemoQuery
    {
        public Money GetMoney() => new Money(1);
    }
```

Edit: the workaround without changing the Money type is to map it explicitly like below. But I still like to know why HotChocolate does not support `record struct` and `struct`

```
 services.AddGraphQLServer()
     .BindRuntimeType<Money, LongType>()
     .AddTypeConverter<Money, long>(money => money.Cents)
  ...
```